# GradientFill API doesn't perform as it should

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, wm-paint

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I want to create a static control with gradient background.

I want to do it the following way:

Create the gradient at the main window’s background, and then place transparent static control on top of that background.

To do that, I have created `RECT` variable in `WM_PAINT` handler that positions the gradient at the position where static control should be.

Also, I try to use double buffering to avoid flickering ( I have also handled `WM_ERASEBKGND`, removed flags `CS_VREDRAW` and `CS_HREDRAW` from window class ).

I have also handled `WM_SIZE` message to invalidate the window, and to reposition static control properly.

In my `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler, I have returned `NULL_BRUSH`.

I have made a demo application to illustrate this, via application wizard in Visual Studio.

I work on Windows XP, using pure Win32 API and C++.

Bellow I will submit the modified code for `WM_PAINT`, and snippets for other handlers listed above:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
         {
             // get rectangle dimensions of the main window

             RECT rec;
             GetClientRect( hWnd, &rec );

             /******* main window's static control ******/

             HWND StaticControl = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Static", L"", 
                                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY,
                                     ( 3 * ( rec.right - rec.left ) / 4 - 340 ) / 3,
                                     120 + ( rec.bottom - rec.top - 450 ) / 3, 
                                     150, 150, hWnd, (HMENU)4000, hInst, 0);
         }
         return (LRESULT)0;

    case WM_SIZE:
        {
             RECT rec; // main window's client rectangle

             GetClientRect( hWnd, &rec ); 

             SetWindowPos( GetDlgItem( hWnd, 4000 ),
                           NULL,
                           ( 3  * ( rec.right - rec.left ) / 4 - 340 ) / 3, 
                           120 + ( rec.bottom - rec.top - 450 ) / 3, 150, 150,
                           SWP_NOZORDER );

            InvalidateRect( hWnd, NULL, FALSE); 
        }
        return (LRESULT)0;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return (LRESULT)1;

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        return (LRESULT)( (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH) );

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

            RECT r; // rectangle for main window's client area

            GetClientRect( hWnd, &r);

            HDC MemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // back buffer

            // compatible bitmap for MemDC

            HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc,
                                                  r.right - r.left, 
                                                  r.bottom - r.top ),
                    oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( MemDC, bmp ); // needed for cleanup

            /***** draw a reference header at the top of the window *******/

            // position it properly at the top

            RECT rect;

            rect.left = r.left;
            rect.top = r.top;
            rect.right = r.right;
            rect.bottom = 120;

            FillRect( MemDC, &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH) );

            /**** main window's gradient background *******/

            //============ down triangle =========//

            TRIVERTEX vertex[3];

            vertex[0].x     = r.right;
            vertex[0].y     = r.bottom - r.top;
            vertex[0].Red   = 0xDB00;
            vertex[0].Green = 0xE500;
            vertex[0].Blue  = 0xF100;
            vertex[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertex[1].x     = r.left;
            vertex[1].y     = r.bottom - r.top;
            vertex[1].Red   = 0x9500;
            vertex[1].Green = 0xB300;
            vertex[1].Blue  = 0xD700;
            vertex[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertex[2].x     = r.left;
            vertex[2].y     = r.top + 120; 
            vertex[2].Red   = 0xDB00;
            vertex[2].Green = 0xE500;
            vertex[2].Blue  = 0xF100;
            vertex[2].Alpha = 0x0000;

            // Create a GRADIENT_TRIANGLE structure that
            // references the TRIVERTEX vertices.

            GRADIENT_TRIANGLE gTriangle;

            gTriangle.Vertex1 = 0;
            gTriangle.Vertex2 = 1;
            gTriangle.Vertex3 = 2;

            // Draw a shaded triangle.

            GradientFill( MemDC, vertex, 3, &gTriangle, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_TRIANGLE);

            //=============== upper triangle =================//

            TRIVERTEX vertex1[3];

            vertex1[0].x     = r.right;
            vertex1[0].y     = r.bottom - r.top;
            vertex1[0].Red   = 0xDB00;
            vertex1[0].Green = 0xE500;
            vertex1[0].Blue  = 0xF100;
            vertex1[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertex1[1].x     = r.right;
            vertex1[1].y     = r.top + 120;
            vertex1[1].Red   = 0x9500;
            vertex1[1].Green = 0xB300;
            vertex1[1].Blue  = 0xD700;
            vertex1[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertex1[2].x     = r.left;
            vertex1[2].y     = r.top + 120; 
            vertex1[2].Red   = 0xDB00;
            vertex1[2].Green = 0xE500;
            vertex1[2].Blue  = 0xF100;
            vertex1[2].Alpha = 0x0000;

            // Draw a shaded triangle.

            GradientFill( MemDC, vertex1, 3, &gTriangle, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_TRIANGLE);

            //**** draw background of the static control ****//

            //position it properly 

            rect.left = ( 3  * ( r.right - r.left ) / 4 - 340 ) / 3;
            rect.top = 120 + ( r.bottom - r.top - 450 ) / 3;
            rect.right = 150 + ( 3  * ( r.right - r.left ) / 4 - 340 ) / 3;
            rect.bottom = 270 + ( r.bottom - r.top - 450 ) / 3; // this one fails!!!

            //FillRect( MemDC, &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) );

            // vertexes for static's gradient color

            //================= top rectangle =====================//

            TRIVERTEX vertexS[2], vertex1S[2] ;

            vertexS[0].x     = rect.left;
            vertexS[0].y     = rect.top;
            vertexS[0].Red   = 0x9500;
            vertexS[0].Green = 0xB300;
            vertexS[0].Blue  = 0xD700;
            vertexS[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertexS[1].x     = rect.right;
            vertexS[1].y     = ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) / 2; 
            vertexS[1].Red   = 0x4F00;
            vertexS[1].Green = 0x8B00;
            vertexS[1].Blue  = 0xBD00;
            vertexS[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

            //================== bottom rectangle ====================//

            vertex1S[0].x     = rect.left;
            vertex1S[0].y     = ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) / 2; 
            vertex1S[0].Red   = 0x4F00;
            vertex1S[0].Green = 0x8B00;
            vertex1S[0].Blue  = 0xBD00;
            vertex1S[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

            vertex1S[1].x     = rect.right;
            vertex1S[1].y     = rect.bottom;
            vertex1S[1].Red   = 0x9500;
            vertex1S[1].Green = 0xB300;
            vertex1S[1].Blue  = 0xD700;
            vertex1S[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

            // Create a GRADIENT_RECT structure that 
            // references the TRIVERTEX vertices.

            GRADIENT_RECT gRect;

            gRect.UpperLeft  = 0;
            gRect.LowerRight = 1;

            // Draw a shaded rectangle. 

            GradientFill( MemDC, vertexS, 2, &gRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V );
            GradientFill( MemDC, vertex1S, 2, &gRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V );

            /****** draw back buffer on the screen DC *****************/

            BitBlt( hdc, 0, 0, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top,
                    MemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

            /************** cleanup *******************/

            SelectObject( MemDC, oldBmp );

            DeleteObject(bmp); // compatible bitmap for MemDC

            DeleteDC(MemDC);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        return (LRESULT)0;
```

### PROBLEM:

When I use `GradientFill` API in `WM_PAINT` handler, I get a bigger rectangle on the screen than it should be.

Bellow picture illustrates this result:

[image]

If I try to fill the same rectangle with some solid brush, everything works fine.

Bellow picture illustrates this result:

[image]

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE PROBLEM:

I have placed breakpoints at the places where rectangle’s coordinates are set and haven't seen any problems.

Also, `GradientFill` returns `TRUE`, so it doesn't fail.

### QUESTION:

How to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simply that your calculations for the vertices are wrong:

```
        vertexS[1].y     = ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) / 2; 
        /* .... */
        vertex1S[0].y     = ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) / 2;
```

Should they be `rect.top + ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) / 2` or something similar? Or even just `rect.bottom` and `rect.top` respectively?

It depends what you're trying to achieve, but either way I think it's currently not what you want. You would need to use `rect.bottom` and `rect.top` to get the same shape that your commented-out `FillRect` draws.

Comment: Mr.Potter, I am trying to create a gradient that has a lighter color at the top and bottom of the rectangle, and darker one in the middle. I thought to fill upper half of the rectangle with the gradient brush that is lighter at the top, and brighter at the bottom. Then, the bottom half of the rectangle would be filled with the brush that is lighter at the bottom, and darker at the top. By filling the rectangle with those 2 brushes, I would achieve the effect of a single gradient brush, which is light at the top and bottom, and dark in the middle. Your solution works, so +1 from me.Thank you.